# Download SSL certificate from aws certificate manager

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-cli

I am using aws certificate manager for managing SSL. Recently I purchased a wildcard ssl `*.example-private.com` Now I need that SSL certificate to deploy on enterprise git instance on aws.

How can i download ssl from aws?

Comment: Side note: If you really **purchased** a certificate, it wasn't from Amazon. Theirs are free.

Comment: @ceejayoz I mean I requested wild card ssl certificate in aws certificate manager and I deployed it on ELB that i have in account.

Comment: @ceejayoz lets say I've git instance with url `git.example-private.com` and I want to deploy ssl over it. what should I do in that case? and forget about the wildcard ssl i.e. `*.example-private.com`

Comment: Put an ELB or CloudFront in front of the instance. Otherwise, you'll need to get an SSL from someone else (Let's Encrypt is free and highly recommended). ACM certificates can't be downloaded for use outside of AWS's built-in integrations like ELBs and CF.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the suggestion. It worked with few tweaks according to my production environment.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You cannot download a SSL certificate from ACM.

Comment: Specifically, from the [ACM FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/): You can use ACM with the following AWS services: Elastic Load Balancing, Amazon CloudFront, Amazon API Gateway, AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I was hoping to use a ACM cert on an EC2 instance... but that's not possible at this time.

Comment: You now can. https://serverfault.com/a/878274/325277

Comment: @rangeme No, you can't. See my comment on that answer. (To clarify: You can get the cert, but so can anyone who visits your site. The cert is public. What OP needs is the *private key*, which you still can't download.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Ah yes, my apologies.

Comment: This answer is incorrect no matter what OP meant. You absolutely **can** download TLS (aka SSL) certificate from ACM, as well as the entire CA certificate chain. But indeed you cannot download its associated *private key*. People would be running into this question and see absolutely incorrect accepted answer. It should be re-phrased like `You can download SSL cert, but you cannot download its private key, therefore ACM certs cannot be used in third-party applications, like enterprise git in your case`

Comment: Bear in mind, that people might want to download TLS certs for purposes different from OPs, say, putting them in the local trust stores. Completely valid case of downloading certs which has nothing to do with the inability to download the private key.

Answer (score 23):

> **Note:** While this can be used to fetch the (already public) *certificate*, it does **not** download the *private key* necessary to use that certificate outside Amazon's systems.

It is now possible to download the certificate with the following command:

aws acm list-certificates  / aws acm get-certificate

Ref:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/get-certificate.html

Comment: Where does this document states that one can download certificate? I didn't see any such option in that document. Could you please share the exact link?

Comment: SO you are right Shailesh, i mistakenly pasted the wrong URL... url updated.

Comment: This gets you the *certificate*, but you can get that with cURL or just by going to the website - it is 100% public information. It does **not** get the *private key*, which means this is useless for OP's purposes.

Comment: @ceejayoz is right. When I want to download SSL that means I want to download its private key so that I can deploy aws acm ssl to any server I want. I think that it's not possible to do it in anyway.

Comment: command is `aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn <arn-here> --output text`

Answer (score 13):

You cannot download from ACM. from the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/):

> Q: Can I use certificates on Amazon EC2 instances or on my own
> servers?
>
> A: No. At this time, certificates provided by ACM can only be used
> with specific AWS services

Comment: Why are you re-answering an old question with the same answer that's been already provided to and accepted by the OP?

Comment: this answer provided more info and context so i'm upvoting it

Answer (score 7):

You can't, but you can get a free one from `https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/`.

Letsencrypt also offers an API backed by open source code to automatically update.